# Slim REST authorization returns empty

Tags: php, slim

This is my function to get the headers.

```
 function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route ) {
    // Getting request headers
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $headers = $app->request()->headers()->all();
    $response = array();

    die(var_export($headers));
  }
```

And what im getting on post man is

```
array (
    Authorization' => '',
      'Host' => 'localhost',
      'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
      'Content-Length' => '0',
      'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
      'Origin' => 'chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop',
      'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36',
      'Postman-Token' => 'bd5e445c-bba1-b7fc-29e6-17724a83dcbd',
      'Accept' => '*/*',
      'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
      'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    )
```

Comment: I have no knowledge of Slim, but I think more information on your setup is needed to be able to help you.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: ahhm, sorry. my question was, why am I not getting authorization in the headers. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to save helper data to collection requests. This will cause the signature to be regenerated each time. These helpers will even work in Newman!

[image]

Enter the username and password fields and hit "Refresh headers" to generate the authorization header.

Please visit [POSTMAN Helpers](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/helpers)

**Update**

For more help [visit here](http://www.salespad.net/getattachment/b6ebb5ef-a957-4fb6-b597-df4c2ce05446/Documentation-SalesPad-WebAPI-Example-Usage-(1).pdf.aspx)

Comment: what account should I use? I mean where do I get the username and the password ?

Comment: username and the password  can be anything just to start session